# Oracle Sql merge table with multiple where clause

Tags: mysql, oracle

My tables:

```
Table 1
Pk     Type       EVENTID    TimeStamp                                Date
1      Audio1          1     11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM           11-JAN-15
2      Video1          1     11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM           11-JAN-15
3      Audio2          2     11-JAN-15 12.35.50.000000000 AM           11-JAN-15
4      Video2          2     11-JAN-15 12.35.50.000000000 AM           11-JAN-15
5      Audio3          3     11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM           11-JAN-15
6      Video3          3     11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM           11-JAN-15
7      Audio4          4     12-JAN-15 12.40.50.000000000 AM           12-JAN-15
8      Video4          4     12-JAN-15 12.40.50.000000000 AM           12-JAN-15


Table 2

Pk    EVENTID      TimeStamp                                
1        1        11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM           
2        2        11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM          
3        3        11-JAN-15 12.35.50.000000000 AM         
4        4        11-JAN-15 12.35.50.000000000 AM         

....
Table 3

Type        Type      EventId           TimeStamp                                Date
Audio1     Video1      1            11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000 AM           11-JAN-15
Audio2     Video2      2            11-JAN-15 12.33.50.000000000 AM           11-JAN-15
Audio3     Video3      3            11-JAN-15 12.35.50.000000000 AM           11-JAN-15
Audio4     Video4      4            11-JAN-15 12.40.50.000000000 AM           12-JAN-15
```

Event is the unique value.

I am looking for a out put like below.

Comment: What's the logic that you're trying to implement?

Comment: You could at least post the format of the output - what do you want to see in resultset

Comment: I want an output like Table 3

Comment: Care to check my answer then? since it gives the exact same output as table 3?

Answer (score -1):

```
Select a.typer, b.typer, a.EVENTID, a.TimeStampField, a.dateField from (
select * from table1 where typer like 'Audio%') a
left join
(select * from table1 where typer like 'Video%') b
on a.EVENTID = b.EVENTID
group by a.typer, b.typer, a.EVENTID, a.TimeStampField, a.dateField;
```

Here you go. This is the output:

```
Type    Type    EVENTID TimeStampField  DateField
Audio1  Video1  1   11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000    11-JAN-15
Audio2  Video2  2   11-JAN-15 12.35.50.000000000    11-JAN-15
Audio3  Video3  3   11-JAN-15 12.33.49.000000000    11-JAN-15
Audio4  Video4  4   12-JAN-15 12.40.50.000000000    12-JAN-15
```

And the sql fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/97718/2

Comment: Can someone explain why the correct answer was downvoted?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Philip.But I am looking with a where clause which satisfies the condition Table1.EVENTID = Table2.EVENTID

Comment: Excuse me? Look at the query, that's exactly what I'm doing. on a.EVENTID = b.EVENTID.  Did you even try running the sql fiddle?

Comment: I am sorry that i din't inform you what I was looking in my query..Your query did work but I have another requirement i.e


Select a.typer, b.typer, a.EVENTID, a.TimeStampField, a.dateField from (
select * from table1 where typer like 'Audio%') a
left join
(select * from table1 where typer like 'Video%') b
on a.EVENTID = b.EVENTID
and
a.TIME_STAMP  >= trunc(sysdate,'ww')
group by a.typer, b.typer, a.EVENTID, a.TimeStampField, a.dateField;


Thanks in advance

Comment: If it worked and you have an unrelated question, then accept the answer and open up a new question.  SO requires 1 question per post.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow.I din't know that.Thanks for the info.